# ¿están en el mismo ámbito este archivo ts y su versión compilada?

Tags: typescript, gulp

Estoy intentando usar gulp-typescript para compilar mi archivo ts y de alguna forma que no logro entender el archivo compilado queda en el mismo ámbito que el archivo ts a pesar de estar a tres padres de diferencia y sin estar siendo llamados desde ningun archivo más allá del gulpfile.

Alguien me puede hacer le favor de explicarme que está pasando aquí? y de ser posible como solucionarlo?

Esta es la única función que tengo en app.ts y es lo único que he compilado de este archivo
[image: Aquí se ve el error en le que me dice que la función está duplica justo después de compilar]

app.js es la version compilada de app.ts y como pueden ver están en diferentes carpetas

[image: Están en distintas carpetas]

Esta es la función que uso para compilar app.ts

[image: Está es la función de gulp con la que compilo]

Aquí una imagen completa con lo que puede ser de interés
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código como texto.

Comment: De que archivo debería añadir más código para el contexto? de app.ts y app.js solo está esa función sum que utilice como test.

Comment: la funcion dentro de gulpfile.js debe ir como texto, la función sum debe ir como texto...